# jQuery ajax send escaped string

Tags: jquery

I am sending some with jquery ajax to the ajax handler file. I am getting from data with jquery, converting them to a json string and sending.

```
var col = $item.data('col');
    var notat   = escape($item.find($("form > ul > li > input[name=notat]")).val());

var saveJson = "";      
    saveJson +="{ \
        'col': '"+col+"', \
        'notat': '"+notat+"' \
    },";


saveJson = saveJson.substring(0, saveJson.length - 1);

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '${ajaxUrl}',
    data: 'action=saveAktorkart&user_id=${user_id}&json='+saveJson,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
        //console.log('Result= '+result)
    }
});
```

Problem is, I am escaping the value of "notat" but in ajax handler it's not getting the escaped value. For example, if the value of "notat" is "asd's", then after escaping it becomes "asd%27s". But in ajax handler, I am again getting "asd's". I am already using "processData: false". But not working

Comment: Why do you need to escape it? Ajax will encode it anyway. BTW, escape() is deprecated, check DOC

Comment: I need to escape the quote inside somehow.

Comment: Will you consider JSON.stringify() to encode instead of building the json string on your own?

Comment: Try sending data as an object `data:{action:"save",user_id:${user_id},colVal:col,notatVal:notat}`